# Open multiple DialogBoxes on clicking multiple Notifications separately

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

Currently I'm working on an android project. What I'm trying is to push notifications to all users. When user clicks on notification, a DialogBox shows the incoming messages.

*What I want to do is : When I send multiple notification, I click on every notification and want to show a DialogBox for each of the notification.

*What I'm facing is : When I send multiple notification, I click on every notification and I'm getting just 1 DialogBox, others dont show any DialogBox.

Below send notfc. code :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, cls);

    intent.putExtra("Title", messageTitle);
    intent.putExtra("Body", messageBody);
    intent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    long[] pattern = {500,500,500,500};

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(pattern)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher2))
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody))//uzun mesajları geniş notification ekranında gösteriyor.
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(nfcId++ /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Below showing Dialogbox codes :

```
private static int openDialog = 0;

public void checkNotificationDialogBox(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    if(this.openDialog == 1){
        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(extras == null){
                title = null;
                body = null;
            }
            else{
                title = extras.getString("Title");
                body = extras.getString("Body");
            }
        }
        else{
            title = (String)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("Title");
            body = (String)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("Body");
        }


        if(!title.isEmpty() && !body.isEmpty()){
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialog.setTitle(this.title);
            dialog.setMessage(this.body);

            dialog.setNegativeButton("İptal", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialog.setPositiveButton("Tamam", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.cancel();

                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }

        openDialog = 0;
    }
}
```

EDIT : I have 2 activity MainActivity and Page2Activity, and I have 2 java class MyFirebaseMessagingService and MyFirebaseInstanceIdService. In MyFirebaseMessagingService on onMessageReceive method:

```
MainActivity mActivity = new MainActivity();
Page2Activity p2a = new Page2Activity();
public static int nfcId = 0;
public static int intentID = 0;

public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message){

    Map<String, String> data = message.getData();

    if(data != null){

        if(isAppRunning(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName())){
            p2a.setOpenDialog(1);
            sendNotification(data.get("title"), data.get("body"), Page2Activity.class);
        }

        else{
            mActivity.setOpenDialog(1);
            sendNotification(data.get("title"), data.get("body"), MainActivity.class);
        }

    }

}
```

And in MainActivity : (below code same for the Page2Activity)

```
private String title;
private String body;
private static int openDialog = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    checkNotificationDialogBox(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: your code doesn't how you're handling `openDialog` changes nor when you call `checkNotificationDialogBox`..

Comment: I have updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on each notification will create new instance of your activity as you are using

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, cls);
```

It is not possible to display multiple dialogs on click of notifications as this is the only way to redirect user from notification to app. You will get new dialog everytime you are redirected to your app.

Comment: I already want to show new Dialogbox for each notification. So how can achieve it?

Comment: Make sure you are not getting Title & Body as blank or null in any case. That might jump you out of your condition and see your previous dialog everytime.

Comment: On every notification I'm getting the proper title and body.

Comment: Btw for ex I'm getting 4 notifications but I'm getting just 1 Dialogbox, not the same dialogbox seeing.